# JMeter connection with proxy

Tags: proxy, jmeter, http-proxy

1.Click the setting
2.Click Advance setting
3.click the "Open proxy setting"
4.click "LAN Setting" 
5.Check the Checkbox "Use a proxy server for your LAN" checkbox and set the Address as "localhost (or) IpAddress" and set a port number "8080"
6.Click the "OK" button
After completion the following steps internet is not connecting to my desktop

Comment: you have set it as "proxy", so internet won't work!

Answer (score 0):

JMeter uses by default port **8888** not **8080** unless you modified it.

If you want to record from behind an enterprise proxy, you need to tell jmeter how to connect to the enterprise proxy, see:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server